# Filezilla Server and Solar Winds SFTP Server security

Tags: security, ftp, windows-server-2012, sftp

For the record it is a Windows 2012 Standard server. I want to set up both a FTP and a SFTP Server. I am using Filezilla Server for FTP and Solar Winds SFTP server for SFTP. Both are services and those services log in as the "Local System account" so....

1) Isn't the "Local System account" the "SYSTEM" user?
2) So all I have to do is give the user "SYSTEM" user full access to the folders at which point the internal security build in to Filezilla and Solar Winds will take effect?

Comment: well, on linux systems, SFTP uses the logged in users identity when authorizing access to files (rather than the root account which runs the service). not sure how the SW version works, but I'd certainly not run the service as system if the service is solely responsible for making authorization decisions.

Comment: Is your question HOW to get your SFTP and FTP services to run as SYSTEM, or SHOULD you configure the SFTP and FTP services to run as SYSTEM? Please edit your question to clarify.